# Probability that binomial distribution is larger than a certain value.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Let $X$ be random value taking values in $\{-1,1\}$, each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and let $X_n$ be the sum of $n$ independent copies of $X$. Then, if I interpreted it correctly, the central limit theorem says that $\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, that is, for each $k\in\mathbb{R}$, $P(X_n\geq k\sqrt{n})\to P(Y\geq k)$, where $Y$ has distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

However, I am interested in how fast $P(X_n\geq k(n)\sqrt{n})$ decreases, where $k(n)$ is a sequence going to infinity. The cases $k(n)=\ln(n)$ and $k(n)=n^\alpha$, for small $\alpha$, should be enough.

Context: I ended up thinking about this while trying to solve a problem in a course about the probabilistic method. I know essentially nothing about statistics, so sorry if this is standard material in statistics courses.

Comment: Generally tails beyond a fixed number of standard deviations are well described by the Chernoff bound.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I think I am looking for something like that. I will look into it

Comment: You are going to want $\alpha <\frac12$.  For $\alpha>\frac12$ you will get a zero probability and for $\alpha=\frac12$ you are asking for $P(X_n\ge n) = \frac1{2^n}$.  In any case, the normal approximation is not always good in the tail of a binomial distribution, and this is more obvious here for $0.4 < \alpha < 0.5$

Comment: @Ian  Here $X$ does not have a Bernoulli distribution and $X_n$ is not binomially distributed.  But $(X_n+n)/2$ is binomially distributed with $p=\frac12$.  So both $X$ and  $X_n/\sqrt{n}$ have mean $0$ and variance $1$

Comment: My bad, sloppy reading on my part.

Comment: @Henry Yes, I want $\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$, in fact when I said $\alpha$ small I mean $\alpha$ should be very close to $0$. I'm almost sure any $\alpha>0$ will work for my problem

Answer (score 1):

If the normal approximation is appropriate in the tail then a reasonable approximation to that approximation might suggest $$P(X_n\geq k(n)\sqrt{n}) \approx \frac{\exp(-k(n)^2/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi} \, k(n)} \tag{1}$$

though the normal approximation is not so good in the tail in your $n^\alpha$ example when $\alpha$ is close to $\frac12$ and no good at all when $\alpha$ is larger than that.

Here is an illustration using R for $k(n)=\log_e(n)$: note the scale is logarithmic to display low probabilities, the actual probabilities are points showing the discreteness of the binomial distribution, the normal tail approximation is in red and the close approximation $(1)$ to that approximation is in blue.

[image]

```
thisfunction <- function(n){ log(n) }
maxn <- 200
n <- 1:maxn
plot(n, pbinom((n+thisfunction(n)*sqrt(n))/2, n, 1/2, lower.tail=FALSE), 
     log="y") 
curve(pnorm(thisfunction(x), lower.tail=FALSE), 
      from=1, to=maxn, add=TRUE, col="red")
curve(exp(-thisfunction(x)^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)/thisfunction(x), 
      from=1, to=maxn, add=TRUE, col="blue")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I said in the first version of my question, this seems to be a matter of how fast $X_n$ converges to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, as if the distribution was exactly $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then I know how to estimate the integral of the tails (like with the bound you give in the answer, or similar bounds for the error function I found in wikipedia)

Comment: @SaúlRM You will always have a discrete distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$, and so the pattern of bumpy precise probabilities you see in the chart.  In terms of the normal approximation, empirically using $n^{0.4}$ leads to normal approximation probabilities which are too high though $n^{0.3}$ does not seem to do the same